# Owl Carousel 2 not Working in wordpress starry theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

Bellow the following Details For My WordPress and Plugin Details.

WordPress Details:

WordPress Version:4.9.8

WordPress jQuery 1.12.4

plugin Details:

owl-carousel jQuery 1.0.0

plugin Version: 2.1

used WordPress Version: 3.0.1 or higher

Tested up to: 4.9.9

[tc-owl-carousel]  Short code

Thank you for giving me clear indications.

Here is the HTML code related to owl carousel:

```
<div class="tcowl-wrap tc-carousel-container">
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme tcowl-nav" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 452px;">
        <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4438px; left: 0px; display: block; transform: translate3d(-317px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hometurph-slider-5.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hometurph-slider-2.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hometurph-slider-3.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hometurph-slider-1.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hometurph-slider-4-1.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/floyd-slider-4-1.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="./wp-content/uploads/2018/12/floyd-slider-1-1.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-controls clickable">
        <div class="owl-pagination">
            <div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span></div>
            <div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am Using plugin Short Code Method in My WordPress. But Owl Carousel Not working in my WordPress. I am using Starry Theme, but I though this theme only Owl Carousel  not Working.

Comment: You can check your console error

Comment: No Error Shows  in Console, But One Warning  i.e..,
(index):2655 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdn.engageto.com/script/5218433daae465a5ffbfb32b3e7bff61.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
(anonymous) @ (index):2655
(anonymous) @ (index):2656

Answer (score 0):

What is the Error indicating in console ?

You can try to change jquery version lower ?

Comment: No Error Shows  in Console, But One Warning  i.e..,


(index):2655 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdn.engageto.com/script/5218433daae465a5ffbfb32b3e7bff61.js with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

(anonymous) @ (index):2655

(anonymous) @ (index):2656

Comment: can you share the site url ?